# Python: Picking a certain element from an array

Tags: python, arrays

I am working with a Excel (csv) file. I have an array as follows:
`[['a','b','c'], ['aber', 'jsfn', 'ff', 'fsf', '003'], [...] ...]`, where each element of the array are not the same size. As we see, the size of the first element is 3 and the size of the second element is 5. In such a case, is it possible to grab the first element of the first element from the array? So if I wanted to pick just 'a' from `['a','b','c']`, would I be able to?

So, if `a = [['a','b','c'], ['aber', 'jsfn', 'ff', 'fsf', '003'], [...] ...]`, would it be possible to do something like `b = a[0,0]`, or...? Note: I am doing all this inside a for loop.

Comment: How are you getting that list?  Are you importing the file in as a CSV?

Comment: Yes, I am importing a csv file.

Comment: Care to show us how you do it?  That is, how are you getting this list?  It may be the case that you're doing a bit too much work and that using `csv` may be a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the first element of your main list with `a[0]`.  Then, you can grab the first element of the the return value with an additional `[0]`, e.g.:

```
b = a[0][0]
```

Ultimately, the above is just shorthand for a more verbose method like:

```
first_list = a[0]
first_element_of_first_list = first_list[0]
```

Now, you mentioned that you are doing all of this in a loop, so here's an example of getting the first element of every list in your main list:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i][0])
```

As user "PM 2Ring" pointed out, the above approach is not the most Pythonic way of implementing the for-loop.  Because the index `i` is not being used to alter the original list, we can use:

```
for row in a:
    print row[0]
```

to achieve the same result as above, but this time we do not need to mess with calculating and using an index.

Comment: While the code in your 3rd code block is perfectly legal, it's not so Pythonic to use `range(len(a))` when you don't really need the index. A better approach uses the logic from your 2nd code block: `for row in a:` `print row[0]`

Comment: I agree.  As the question seems to be regarding list indexing, I opted to go for the `range(len(a))` approach, but you are right; because the index is not necessarily needed in this case (there is no need to alter the original list), the method you wrote is indeed more Pythonic.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess the more examples of list indexing that Joola sees, the better. :)

Comment: I'll go ahead and add an example of the more Pythonic approach to the answer.

Comment: @JoojoJobala: Sorry for mis-spelling your name in my previous comment. If you like Zachary's answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have this list of lists:

```
alist = [['a','b','c'], ['aber', 'jsfn', 'ff', 'fsf', '003'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If you want to retrieve the first element of every list in `alist`, then:

```
>>> [x[0] for x in alist]
['a', 'aber', 1]
```

#### Alternative: Retrieving the last elements

In python, the last element of a list is number `-1`.  So:

```
>>> [x[-1] for x in alist]
['c', '003', 3]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you grab the last element of each element? So, if we wanted ['c','003',3] instead of ['a', 'aber', 1], how would we do that?

Comment: @JoojoJobala Python specializes in simple and elegant.